# How to override Index's IsUnique in inherited class

Tags: entity-framework-core, data-annotations

I have following base class

```
[Index(nameof(FullName), IsUnique = true)]
public abstract class Entity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

and another class that inherits it

```
[Index(nameof(FullName), IsUnique = false)]
public class Citizen : Entity
{
   
}
```

So, I am trying to override `IsUnique`, but Entity Framework Core is creating **Citizen** table with Unique index in SQL Server database.

How to override or disable `IsUnique` on inherited class (without using model builder)?